# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.quartz.JobDataMap.put(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

after upgrading spring version 3.1.3 to 4.2.2 i'm getting this kind of Exception and i'm using quartz-schedular 2.0.1 version
it is showing error at xml file

```
   <bean id=refreshMethod" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetObject" ref="dataStore" />
      <property name="targetMethod" value="refreshForAll" />
    </bean>
```

following is exception stack trace

```
exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.quartz.JobDataMap.put(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 25 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.quartz.JobDataMap.put(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 40 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try upgrading quartz to version 2.2.1.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
<artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version></dependency>
```

Comment: Indeed, if you look at the javadoc, 2.2.1 does have a String,Object method:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/utils/StringKeyDirtyFlagMap.html

And 2.0.1 does not: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/previous_versions/2.0.2/index.html